# How to make C# write commands in Microsoft Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, automation

Im trying to run ulozto-downloader app with Microsoft Powershell with C#. But Im not very good at this part of C#. I want to open Microsoft PowerShell and write this command:
ulozto-downloader --parts 50 "URL" then wait till it finishes and write another one command but with different URL. URLs can be pre-stored in code. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I think this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.2) may be useful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.